# How Can I switch the session storage according to the client on Ruby on Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, session-store, session-storage

I have a question about sessions on ruby-on-rails. 
We have a several options about session storage such as cookie, active_record_store, etc..
I primarily use the cookie storage, but, there are some client which doesn't support cookie function. In that case, I have to make that client to use the "active_record_store". 
My rails version is 2.3.5.
I found out that even though I use the active_record_store, the cookie is still available.
In my situation, both session storage might be available.
So, I want to make the framework to primarily use the cookie, when the cookie is available.
On the other hand, the client doesn't support the cookie, secondly to use the active_record_store.

I think this function requires some override to the framework, but I don't know how to do it.
Do you have any idea for that?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your client can't stock cookie, you can't have a session_store. Even in active_record.

The session system know which session you have with save session_id in cookie. So if your client refuse cookie. You can't have session system.

But your can hack a little to make a system where the cookie store is pass in URL params.